# key error when writing dictionaries with common keys to csv

Tags: python, dictionary

I trying to write a few dictionaries with common keys to a csv, but keep getting a key error:

```
TotalData = dict1, dict2, dict3

with open(self.pathString, 'wb') as ofile:
   writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='\t')
   writer.writerow(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
       for key in sorted(ConsoSom.iterkeys(), key=lambda x: str(x)):
           writer.writerow([key] + ['{0:.2f}'.format(d[key]) for d in TotalData])
```

My error gives me KeyError: u'dict3key'

UPDATE: This is because the keys are not always present. I am wondering how to leave a blank space if the key is not present.

my desired result is:

```
field1, field2, field3
id1, value1, second1
id2,  , second2
id3, value3, second3
```

Comment: Is that key in all three dictionaries?

Comment: @wwii great question. it is possible that sometimes the key is missing. I'm now wondering how to write the value only if the key is present (meaning, leave a blank if it is not).

Comment: How about `print(ConsoSom.keys())` and `print([d.keys() for d in TotalData])`. Its quite likely that 'dict3key' isn'tin all of them.

Comment: try `d.get(key, somedefaultvalue)` instead of `d[key]`

Comment: @tdelaney this is exactly my problem, i've updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Use `dict.get`:

```
TotalData = dict1, dict2, dict3

with open(self.pathString, 'wb') as ofile:
   writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='\t')
   writer.writerow(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
       for key in sorted(ConsoSom.iterkeys(), key=lambda x: str(x)):
           writer.writerow([key] + ['{0:.2f}'.format(d.get(key, 0)) for d in TotalData])
```